# get text of xml element is not working: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall'

Tags: python, xml

The code below is getting information about a artist using lastfm api. Then it stores the name in `bands[Name]` and each tag name(ex: rock, etc) of the artist in the `bands[Tags].` Its working fine to get and store the name but its not working for the tags. It appears:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Ozzy/PycharmProjects/getData/getData.py", line 19, in <module>
        for tag in artist.find('tags').findall('tag'):
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall'
```

**Minimum working exemple to demonstrate the error:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import requests

    ID = 1

    chosen = "U2"
    artist = requests.get(
        'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=U2&api_key=b088cbedecd40b35dd89e90f55227ac2')
    tree = ET.fromstring(artist.content)
    for child in tree:
        for artist in child:
            print(artist)
            for tag in artist.find('tags').findall('tag'):
                print(tag.find('name').text)
```

**The response have this format:**

```
<lfm status="ok">
<artist>
<name>U2</name>
<tags>
<tag>
<name>rock</name>
<url>https://www.last.fm/tag/rock</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<tag>
<name>alternative</name>
<url>https://www.last.fm/tag/alternative</url>
</tag>
</tags>  
</artist>
</lfm>
```

**Full working exemple, the code gets the top artists from a specific country and then collect info about the artist (without getting and storing the tags of each artist working because it appears the NoneType error above):**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import json
ID = 1

api_key = "b088cbedecd40b35dd89e90f55227ac2" 

bands = {}
# GET TOP ARTISTS
for i in range(2, 3):
    artistslist = requests.get(
        'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&page='+str(i) +'&api_key=' + api_key)
    tree = ET.fromstring(artistslist.content)
    for child in tree:
        for artist in child.findall('artist'):
            name = artist.find('name').text
            url = artist.find('url').text
            bands[ID] = {}
            bands[ID]['ID'] = ID
            bands[ID]['Name'] = name
            bands[ID]['URL'] = url
            ID += 1



# GET ARTIST INFO
for i, v in bands.items():

    chosen = bands[i]['Name'].replace(" ", "+")
    artist = requests.get(
        'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=' + chosen + '&api_key=' + api_key)
    tree = ET.fromstring(artist.content)
    for child in tree:
        for artist in child:
            #for tag in artist.find('tags').findall('tag'):
                #print(tag.find('name').text)
                #bands[i][Tags] = tag.find('name').text


            if (artist.get('size') == "large"):
                if (artist.text is not None):
                    bands[i]['Image'] = artist.text
            for bio in artist.findall('summary'):
                if (bio.text is not None):
                    bands[i]['Description'] = bio.text
                else:
                    bands[i]['Description'] = bio.text
    print(bands[i]['Name'] + " INFO RETRIEVED")

with open('artists.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(bands, outfile)

with open('artists.json') as data_file:
    bands = json.load(data_file)

data_file.close()
```

Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall' this means artist.find('tags') is not able to find any tags hence returning you a None value

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in the xml response there is the "tags" element so it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops go one level too deep.

```
<lfm status="ok">       --> tree
  <artist>                --> child in tree
    <name>U2</name>         --> for artist in child
    <tags>..</tags>
```

`<tags` is already part of `child` and therefore `artist.find('tags')` will return `None`.

You can shorten your loop to:

```
for band in bands.values():       
    url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist={}&api_key={}'.format(band['Name'], api_key)
    artist = requests.get(url)
    tree = ET.fromstring(artist.content)
    if tree.find('artist') is None:
        continue
    for child in tree.find('artist').getchildren():
        if child.get('size') == "large":
            if (child.text is not None):
                band['Image'] = child.text
        for bio in child.findall('summary'):
            if bio.text is not None:
                band['Description'] = bio.text
            else:
                band['Description'] = ""
        for tag in child.findall('tag'):
            if band.get('Tags'):
                band['Tags'].append(tag.find('name').text)
            else:
                band['Tags'] = [tag.find('name').text]
    print(band['Name'] + " INFO RETRIEVED")
```

---

A few notes:

- It is easier and more efficient to loop over the keys in a `dict` by using `for k in my_dict` or over the values with `for val in my_dict.values()`
- You are overwriting your `Tags` with the last value, using a `list` and appending to it will make sure you save all values
- Your `if/else` statement (`if (bio.text is not None):`) behaves identical independent of the condition

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation, it Works. But Im not understanding the third note, if is not none it stores the text of the xml element, if its none it stores 'None' it seems ok, no?

Comment: You are using `bands[i]['Description'] = bio.text` in both cases which is OK but once you get a `string` and once you get `None`. Imagine you want to do something with a string and it will throw an error for `None`.